# Maintaining order in large list of movies/ratings

Tags: python, bigdata

I have a text file with hundreds of thousands of students, and their ratings for certain films organized with the first word being the student number, the second being the name of the movie (with no spaces), and the third being the rating they gave the movie:

```
student1000 Thor 1
student1001 Superbad -3
student1002 Prince_of_Persia:_The_Sands_of_Time 5
student1003 Old_School 3
student1004 Inception 5
student1005 Finding_Nemo 3
student1006 Tangled 5
```

I would like to arrange them in a dictionary so that I have each student mapped to a list of their movie ratings, where the ratings are in the same order for each student.  In other words, I would like to have it like this:

```
{student1000 : [1, 3, -5, 0, 0, 3, 0,...]}
{student1001 : [0, 1, 0, 0, -3, 0, 1,...]}
```

Such that the first, second, third, etc. ratings for each student correspond to the same movies.  The order is completely random for movies AND student numbers, and I'm having quite a bit of trouble doing this effectively.  Any help in coming up with something that will minimize the big-O complexity of this problem would be awesome.

**I ended up figuring it out.  Here's the code I used for anyone wondering:**

```
def get_movie_data(fileLoc):
    movieDic = {}
    movieList = set()

    f = open(fileLoc)
    setHold = set()
    for line in f:
        setHold.add(line.split()[1])
    f.close()
    movieList = sorted(setHold)

    f = open(fileLoc)
    for line in f:
        hold = line.strip().split()
        student = hold[0]
        movie = hold[1]
        rating = int(hold[2])
        if student not in movieDic:
            lst = [0]*len(movieList)
            movieDic[student] = lst
        hold2 = movieList.index(movie)
        rate = movieDic[student]
        rate[hold2] = rating
    f.close()
    return movieList, movieDic
```

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can first build a dictionary of dictionaries:

```
{
 'student1000' : {'Thor': 1, 'Superbad': 3, ...}, 
 'student1001' : {'Thor': 0, 'Superbad': 1, ...},
 ...
}
```

Then you can go through that to get a master list of all the movies, establish an order for them (corresponding to the order within each student's rating list), and finally go through each student in the dictionary, converting the dictionary to the list you want. Or, like another answer said, just keep it as a dictionary.

[defaultdict](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict) will probably come in handy. It lets you say that the default value for each student is an empty list (or dictionary) so you don't have to initialize it before you start appending values (or setting key-value pairs).

```
from collections import defaultdict

students = defaultdict(dict)
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    for line in f.readlines():
        elts = line.split()
        student = elts[0]
        movie = elts[1]
        rating = int(elts[2])
        students[student][movie] = rating
```

Answer (score 1):

So, the answers here are functionally the same as what you seem to be looking for, but as far as directly constructing the lists you're looking for, they seem to be answering slightly different questions. Personally I would prefer to do this in a more dynamic way. Since it doesn't seem to me like you actually know the movies that are going to be rated ahead of time, you've gotta keep some kind of running tally of that.

```
ratings = {}   
allMovies = [] 
    for line in file:
        info = line.split(" ")
        movie = info[1].strip().lower()
        student = info[0].strip().lower()
        rating = float(info[2].strip().lower())
        if movie not in allMovies:
            allMovies.append(movie)
        movieIndex = allMovies.index(movie)
        if student not in ratings:
            ratings[student] = ([0]*(len(allMovies)-1)).append(rating)
        else:
            if len(allMovies) > len(ratings[student]):
                ratings[student] = ratings[student].extend([0]*(len(allMovies)-len(ratings[student]))
            ratings[student][movieIndex] = rating
```

It's not the way I would approach this problem, but I think this solution is closest to the original intent of the question and you can use a buffer to feed in the lines if there's a memory issue, but unless your file is multiple gigabytes there shouldn't be an issue with that.

Comment: This looks like it's what I'm looking for.  However, the variable "ratings[student]" gives an error when I try to get the length because it is a Nonetype.  I'm not extremely familiar with Python types, but how might I let the computer know that it's a list?

Comment: If you just say ratings[student] = [] It should let python know it's a list. It should be instantiating the list in the loop of if student not in ratings. Could you post a little more in depth as to your exact error and implementation?

Answer (score 0):

Just put the scores into a dictionary rather than a list. After you've read all the data, you can then extract the movie names and put them in any order you want. Assuming students can rate different movies, maintaining some kind of consistent order while reading the file, without knowing the order of the movies to begin with, seems like a lot of work.

If you're worrying about the keys taking up a lot of memory, use `intern()` on the keys to make sure you're only storing one copy of each string.